# In wicket, how to make the page re-init when back button is hit

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

I'm using Wicket 6, and we have a situation where a user is hitting back and it's loading the page without initializing it from the page history.  I want the page init to run so that data is read fresh and things are in the proper state.  How can I make wicket do this?

I thought I was already doing this with a custom MountedMapper that someone had suggested long ago, but I have a breakpoint in the page constructor (the one that accepts PageParameters) and it's not running.

The custom MountedMapper:

```
  if (requestHandler instanceof ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler || requestHandler instanceof BookmarkableListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) { 
      return null; 
  } else { 
       return super.mapHandler(requestHandler); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make your page stateless, so it is recreated on each access.

Or improved your page, so that it loads fresh data on each render:
either use appropriate models that automatically deliver up-to-date data or override #onConfigure() and update,